# VBScript to move all files from one folder to another

Tags: vbscript

For example from `\\10.10.10.10\Share\*` to `\\10.10.10.20\Share\*`.

Can someone please help out with an example or point me in the right direction?

As simple as possible is good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    .MoveFile "\\10.10.10.10\Share\*.*", "\\10.10.10.20\Share\"
End With
```

Comment: @JoaoFilipeClementeMartins An error will occur. You can 1. Handle the error, 2. Clear the dest folder beforehand, or 3. Iterate file by file testing for the existence of each instead of using a single wildcard move operation. You could also try `CopyFile()` instead which allows you to pass an optional third parameter indicating whether you'd like to overwrite an existing file.

Answer (score 2):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198719.aspx

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objFSO.MoveFile "\\10.10.10.10\Share\*.*" , "\\10.10.10.20\Share"
```

If you're moving to a location that already has files with the same names as the ones you're moving, you need to delete them from the destination first.

Comment: Just a tip: it's a good idea to specify the dest folder with a trailing backslash. Doesn't make a difference in this example, but if you were moving a single file, VBScript would attempt to *create a file* named `Share` instead of moving it into the folder named `Share`.

Answer (score 2):

Another simple solution would be

```
For Each file in fso
    'make moving
Next
```